# Navigating real time with USB GPS usiang QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps

I'm trying to navigate real time with an USB GPS over a shapefile map, but I can't find the way to do this. I'm using QGIS 1.9.0 desktop version with a Garmin Etrex Legend HCx GPS.

In fisrt place, QGIS doesn't recognise my GPS port. In addition, I cannot find in QGIS the option to navigate real time.

Do you have any idea to help me with this?

Comment: Garmin Etrex Legend connected with QGIS http://nickmcw.wordpress.com/2010/07/30/quantum-gis-using-a-usb-gps-device/

Comment: Also from the link that @Mapperz provided is another link that may shed some more light on the subject: http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Gps_units_download_data_and_live_tracking#On-MS-Windows

Answer (score 3):

Working on Windows 7, I can connect my Etrex Legend Hcx to QGIS with live tracking using Franson GPS Gate Client from http://gpsgate.com/products/gpsgate_client.

This free software redirects the GPS data from USB to a virtual COM port.

Having that started, you can activate logging in QGIS with `View -> Panels -> GPS Information`

Set `Connect`to `Autoconnect`and then click on `Connect`

Answer (score 1):

Note that this feature is now built-in to QGIS as of at least version 2.8

https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_gps/live_GPS_tracking.html and exists at the time I write this in 3.6.